# Can replace the state in Redux.createStore?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have no idea for this problem. So share your knowledge with me. This is my recuirement.

Comment: Please explain your problem in detail. With what you have tried till now. Then we can help.

Comment: I have tried to replace the whole state in store. But I can't replace whole store into new state. You have any idea to replace the whole state to new state?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I cleared my doubt. Redux doesn't allow state to replace. The State is read only. State should be changed only with actions, without any other force. This makes application more predictable and safe.